# How can I reach the elements of the appeared pop-up using selenium?

Tags: selenium, popup, alert, frame, mousehover

In the following ecommerce site "https://www.gittigidiyor.com/", I want to click on "giris yap" button using selenium java but the problem is whenever I hover the mouse to profile icon, this pop-up appears and i try to inspect the pop-up to see the element but nothing happened. Could you please help me how can i click the buttons of this pop-up. I tried by switching to alert/frame but it did not work[opened login popup in the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Ce3.jpg)

Comment: could you add the website link

Comment: https://www.gittigidiyor.com/

Comment: which langugae are you using

Comment: I have edited the issue description and added java there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get("https://www.gittigidiyor.com")
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title=\"Giriş Yap\"]")).click()
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[data-cy=\"header-login-button\"]"))).click();
```

To find the element use below technique:

To search xpath of such dynamic elements use DOM break points:

[image]

And select break on subtree modification. Now all changes will break and pause the webpage rendering

[image]

Click resume execution or press f8 till your span gets displayed